# How to enable the login for the default windows authentication? error:18470

Tags: sql-server, windows-authentication

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZXeq.png)

I'm trying to connect to the default or normal windows authentication. It was my mistake to disable the default and now I can't access it. Help pls!

Comment: are there any other users you could reach out to ?

Comment: even my administrator account can't login. i got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You cant disable both windows and SQL auth( as I understand from your question,it seems some of your accounts are disabled.here is one way which will help if you are admin on box,this helps in adding a new account as admin ...

1.Stop sql server service from sql service configuration manager
2.start sql server in single user mode

```
 Using configuration Manager 
    ◾Locate the service which you have stopped earlier. Go to its   
properties, “Advanced”, 
click on drop down at “Startup Parameters”  and add ;-mSQLCMD
```

3.Open administrator command prompt. 
(i.e. right click on command prompt shortcut and choose “Run As Administrator”

◦Type sqlcmd –S 
    For example
 ◾sqlcmd –S. (for default instance)
  ◾sqlcmd –S.\MyInstance

4.now run below script

```
USE [master]
GO
CREATE LOGIN [BUILTIN\Administrators] FROM WINDOWS WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master]
GO
EXEC master..sp_addsrvrolemember @loginame = N’BUILTIN\Administrators’, @rolename = N’sysadmin’
GO
```

please note you should be part of builtin administrators group which you can add by typing lusrmgr.msc in run..

below is the blog post FYR...

http://sqlserver-help.com/2012/02/08/help-i-lost-sa-password-and-no-one-has-system-administrator-sysadmin-permission-what-should-i-do/